# Jspersoft, How to change the null label in input controls from "---" to "ALL"?

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

How to change the null label in input controls from "---" to "ALL"?

The input control is combobox,
single value select query.

Comment: Are you showing label like `$P{someParamerterOrField} + "---"`? Can you post your jrxml file?

Comment: when I use a non mandatory, visible , combo box, single select from query input control - it shows me all of the selected values plus a "---" default label (NULL value) option

Answer (score 0):

you can create variable and put this parameter in. Then use replace on the input parameter where you change value of input parameter from "---" to "ALL". After all use this variable instead of input parameter.

hope this help :)

Comment: thanks, but I want the value to stay the same and only the label which the user sees to change from --- to "ALL"

Comment: So apply the same logic with replace function to text field in report. I am afraid that you can not change the name/label of input parameter as technical field on background. Only the way how to display it directly in report.

Answer (score 0):

"---" actually represents a null value in Input Controls.

You could make the Input Control mandatory, and it will remove the null value.